# python messed up on my laptop

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management

I downloaded and installed python3 from source; after which I removed it.
As a result, there appears to be an issue with `apt-get` as there are multiple packages that can't be installed properly. See below:

```
dovl@dov-laptop:$ sudo apt-get install meld
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 meld : Depends: python-gi (>= 3.8) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: python-gi-cairo but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried fixing this with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall` as I saw suggested in one of the answers, however this didn't fix the problem.

```
dovl@dov-laptop:$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of python is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
```

How can I fix my installation and packages to the point where I can download packages properly? I'll be happy to provide more information should it be required.

Answer (score 1):

After (even more) trial and error, it turns out that I had to remove python, which was set to python3.6 and reinstall python2.7. The Synaptic Package Manager was extremely useful in facilitating this.